# A private copy of a Google Sheet for each person allowed to access the master spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I prepared a Google Sheet that allows me to simulate many budget allocations that my local government could grant to requesting companies. Stuff like "the government will fund 50% of expenses of type a and type b up to a maximum of 80% of expenses of type c".

Ideally I would like to share this spreadsheet with everyone interested, but each user should have access to her or his own copy. If they all get access to the same sheet in fact they will work on the same budget simulation, while I would like for everyone to use a "private" simulation.

Do you know if that's possible in Google Sheets? If yes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Ask your users to create their own copies, by using the menu option, File-> Make a copy
And they can store it to their own private GDrive space, and work away.

Additionally, you can make the original simulation spreadsheet non-editable, by first moving it out of a shared folder, and then changing the link access.

It is explained well here: https://support.google.com/docs/thread/11499140?hl=en